# How to meaningfully extract information from a JSON reply?

Tags: java, json, weather

### Reply for Mumbai, India

```
{   "response": {       "version": "0.1"        
"termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html"        
"features": {       "geolookup": 1      
        "conditions": 1     
        "forecast": 1       }   }       
    "location": {       "type":"INTLCITY"
        "country":"IN"
        "country_iso3166":"IN"
        "country_name":"India"
        "state":""
        "city":"Mumbai"
        "tz_short":"IST"
        "tz_long":"Asia/Kolkata"
        "lat":"19.12000084"
        "lon":"72.84999847"
        "zip":"00000"
        "magic":"1"
        "wmo":"43003"
        "l":"/q/zmw:00000.1.43003"
        "requesturl":"global/stations/43003.html"
        "wuiurl":"http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/43003.html"
        "nearby_weather_stations": {        "airport": {        "station": [        { "city":"Mumbai / Santacruz"
 "state":""
 "country":"India"
 "icao":"VABB"
 "lat":"19.11666679"
 "lon":"72.84999847" }
        { "city":"Mumbai"
 "state":""
 "country":"IN"
 "icao":"VABB"
 "lat":"19.12000084"
 "lon":"72.84999847" }      ]       }       
        "pws": {        "station": [        ]       }       }   }       
    "current_observation": {        "image": {      "url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png"
        "title":"Weather Underground"
        "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"        }
        "display_location": {       "full":"Mumbai
 India"
        "city":"Mumbai"
        "state":""
        "state_name":"India"
        "country":"IN"
        "country_iso3166":"IN"
        "zip":"00000"
        "latitude":"19.12000084"
        "longitude":"72.84999847"
        "elevation":"14.00000000"       }
        "observation_location": {       "full":"Mumbai
 "
        "city":"Mumbai"
        "state":""
        "country":"IN"
        "country_iso3166":"IN"
        "latitude":"19.12000084"
        "longitude":"72.84999847"
        "elevation":"46 ft"     }
        "estimated": {      }
        "station_id":"VABB"
        "observation_time":"Last Updated on February 16
 5:10 PM IST"
        "observation_time_rfc822":"Sat
 16 Feb 2013 17:10:00 +0530"
        "observation_epoch":"1361014800"
        "local_time_rfc822":"Sat
 16 Feb 2013 17:25:20 +0530"
        "local_epoch":"1361015720"
        "local_tz_short":"IST"
        "local_tz_long":"Asia/Kolkata"
        "local_tz_offset":"+0530"
        "weather":"Clear"
        "temperature_string":"77 F (25 C)"
        "temp_f":77
        "temp_c":25
        "relative_humidity":"54%"
        "wind_string":"From the WNW at 8 MPH"
        "wind_dir":"WNW"
        "wind_degrees":290
        "wind_mph":8
        "wind_gust_mph":0
        "wind_kph":13
        "wind_gust_kph":0
        "pressure_mb":"1008"
        "pressure_in":"29.77"
        "pressure_trend":"0"
        "dewpoint_string":"59 F (15 C)"
        "dewpoint_f":59
        "dewpoint_c":15
        "heat_index_string":"NA"
        "heat_index_f":"NA"
        "heat_index_c":"NA"
        "windchill_string":"NA"
        "windchill_f":"NA"
        "windchill_c":"NA"
        "feelslike_string":"77 F (25 C)"
        "feelslike_f":"77"
        "feelslike_c":"25"
        "visibility_mi":"3.7"
        "visibility_km":"6.0"
        "solarradiation":""
        "UV":"-1"
        "precip_1hr_string":"-9999.00 in (-9999.00 mm)"
        "precip_1hr_in":"-9999.00"
        "precip_1hr_metric":"-9999.00"
        "precip_today_string":"0.00 in (0.0 mm)"
        "precip_today_in":"0.00"
        "precip_today_metric":"0.0"
        "icon":"clear"
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif"
        "forecast_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/43003.html"
        "history_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/VABB/2013/2/16/DailyHistory.html"
        "ob_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=19.12000084
72.84999847"    }       
    "forecast":{        "txt_forecast": {       "date":"5:30 AM IST"
        "forecastday": [        {       "period":0
        "icon":"chancerain"
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/chancerain.gif"
        "title":"Saturday"
        "fcttext":"Partly cloudy with a chance of rain in the morning
 then clear. High of 81F. Winds from the WNW at 10 to 15 mph. Chance of rain 30%."
        "fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy with a chance of rain in the morning
 then clear. High of 27C. Breezy. Winds from the WNW at 15 to 25 km/h. Chance of rain 30%."
        "pop":"30"      }       
        {       "period":1
        "icon":"clear"
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif"
        "title":"Saturday Night"
        "fcttext":"Clear. Low of 68F. Winds less than 5 mph."
        "fcttext_metric":"Clear. Low of 20C. Winds less than 5 km/h."
        "pop":"0"       }       
        {       "period":2
        "icon":"clear"
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif"
        "title":"Sunday"
        "fcttext":"Clear. High of 82F. Winds from the NE at 5 to 15 mph shifting to the WNW in the afternoon."
        "fcttext_metric":"Clear. High of 28C. Winds from the NE at 5 to 20 km/h shifting to the WNW in the afternoon."
        "pop":"0"       }       
        {       "period":3
        "icon":"clear"
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif"
        "title":"Sunday Night"
        "fcttext":"Clear. Low of 66F. Winds from the NNE at 5 to 10 mph."
        "fcttext_metric":"Clear. Low of 19C. Winds from the NNE at 10 to 15 km/h."
        "pop":"0"       }       
        {       "period":4
        "icon":"clear"
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif"
        "title":"Monday"
        "fcttext":"Clear. High of 88F. Winds from the NNE at 5 to 15 mph shifting to the NW in the afternoon."
        "fcttext_metric":"Clear. High of 31C. Breezy. Winds from the NNE at 10 to 20 km/h shifting to the NW in the afternoon."
        "pop":"0"       }       
        {       "period":5
        "icon":"clear"
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif"
        "title":"Monday Night"
        "fcttext":"Clear. Low of 63F. Winds from the NNE at 5 to 10 mph."
        "fcttext_metric":"Clear. Low of 17C. Winds from the NNE at 5 to 15 km/h."
        "pop":"0"       }       
        {       "period":6
        "icon":"clear"
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif"
        "title":"Tuesday"
        "fcttext":"Clear. High of 90F. Winds from the North at 5 to 10 mph shifting to the WNW in the afternoon."
        "fcttext_metric":"Clear. High of 32C. Winds from the North at 5 to 20 km/h shifting to the WNW in the afternoon."
        "pop":"0"       }       
        {       "period":7
        "icon":"clear"
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif"
        "title":"Tuesday Night"
        "fcttext":"Clear. Low of 72F. Winds from the North at 5 to 10 mph."
        "fcttext_metric":"Clear. Low of 22C. Winds from the North at 5 to 15 km/h."
        "pop":"0"       }       ]       }
        "simpleforecast": {     "forecastday": [        {"date":{   "epoch":"1361037600"
    "pretty":"11:30 PM IST on February 16
 2013"
    "day":16
    "month":2
    "year":2013
    "yday":46
    "hour":23
    "min":"30"
    "sec":0
    "isdst":"0"
    "monthname":"February"
    "weekday_short":"Sat"
    "weekday":"Saturday"
    "ampm":"PM"
    "tz_short":"IST"
    "tz_long":"Asia/Kolkata"}
        "period":1
        "high": {       "fahrenheit":"81"
        "celsius":"27"      }
        "low": {        "fahrenheit":"68"
        "celsius":"20"      }
        "conditions":"Chance of Rain"
        "icon":"chancerain"
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/chancerain.gif"
        "skyicon":"mostlysunny"
        "pop":30
        "qpf_allday": {     "in": 0.01
        "mm": 0.3       }
        "qpf_day": {        "in": 0.00
        "mm": 0.0       }
        "qpf_night": {      "in": 0.00
        "mm": 0.0       }
        "snow_allday": {        "in": 0
        "cm": 0     }
        "snow_day": {       "in": 0
        "cm": 0     }
        "snow_night": {     "in": 0
        "cm": 0     }
        "maxwind": {        "mph": 14
        "kph": 22
        "dir": "WNW"
        "degrees": 294      }
        "avewind": {        "mph": 12
        "kph": 19
        "dir": "WNW"
        "degrees": 295      }
        "avehumidity": 53
        "maxhumidity": 72
        "minhumidity": 49       }       
        {"date":{   "epoch":"1361124000"
    "pretty":"11:30 PM IST on February 17
 2013"
    "day":17
    "month":2
    "year":2013
    "yday":47
    "hour":23
    "min":"30"
    "sec":0
    "isdst":"0"
    "monthname":"February"
    "weekday_short":"Sun"
    "weekday":"Sunday"
    "ampm":"PM"
    "tz_short":"IST"
    "tz_long":"Asia/Kolkata"}
        "period":2
        "high": {       "fahrenheit":"82"
        "celsius":"28"      }
        "low": {        "fahrenheit":"66"
        "celsius":"19"      }
        "conditions":"Clear"
        "icon":"clear"
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif"
        "skyicon":"sunny"
        "pop":0
        "qpf_allday": {     "in": 0.00
        "mm": 0.0       }
        "qpf_day": {        "in": 0.00
        "mm": 0.0       }
        "qpf_night": {      "in": 0.00
        "mm": 0.0       }
        "snow_allday": {        "in": 0
        "cm": 0     }
        "snow_day": {       "in": 0
        "cm": 0     }
        "snow_night": {     "in": 0
        "cm": 0     }
        "maxwind": {        "mph": 11
        "kph": 18
        "dir": "NW"
        "degrees": 306      }
        "avewind": {        "mph": 8
        "kph": 13
        "dir": "WSW"
        "degrees": 238      }
        "avehumidity": 55
        "maxhumidity": 64
        "minhumidity": 39       }       
        {"date":{   "epoch":"1361210400"
    "pretty":"11:30 PM IST on February 18
 2013"
    "day":18
    "month":2
    "year":2013
    "yday":48
    "hour":23
    "min":"30"
    "sec":0
    "isdst":"0"
    "monthname":"February"
    "weekday_short":"Mon"
    "weekday":"Monday"
    "ampm":"PM"
    "tz_short":"IST"
    "tz_long":"Asia/Kolkata"}
        "period":3
        "high": {       "fahrenheit":"88"
        "celsius":"31"      }
        "low": {        "fahrenheit":"63"
        "celsius":"17"      }
        "conditions":"Clear"
        "icon":"clear"
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif"
        "skyicon":"sunny"
        "pop":0
        "qpf_allday": {     "in": 0.00
        "mm": 0.0       }
        "qpf_day": {        "in": 0.00
        "mm": 0.0       }
        "qpf_night": {      "in": 0.00
        "mm": 0.0       }
        "snow_allday": {        "in": 0
        "cm": 0     }
        "snow_day": {       "in": 0
        "cm": 0     }
        "snow_night": {     "in": 0
        "cm": 0     }
        "maxwind": {        "mph": 12
        "kph": 19
        "dir": "NW"
        "degrees": 310      }
        "avewind": {        "mph": 9
        "kph": 14
        "dir": "SW"
        "degrees": 235      }
        "avehumidity": 44
        "maxhumidity": 62
        "minhumidity": 30       }       
        {"date":{   "epoch":"1361296800"
    "pretty":"11:30 PM IST on February 19
 2013"
    "day":19
    "month":2
    "year":2013
    "yday":49
    "hour":23
    "min":"30"
    "sec":0
    "isdst":"0"
    "monthname":"February"
    "weekday_short":"Tue"
    "weekday":"Tuesday"
    "ampm":"PM"
    "tz_short":"IST"
    "tz_long":"Asia/Kolkata"}
        "period":4
        "high": {       "fahrenheit":"90"
        "celsius":"32"      }
        "low": {        "fahrenheit":"72"
        "celsius":"22"      }
        "conditions":"Clear"
        "icon":"clear"
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif"
        "skyicon":"sunny"
        "pop":0
        "qpf_allday": {     "in": 0.00
        "mm": 0.0       }
        "qpf_day": {        "in": 0.00
        "mm": 0.0       }
        "qpf_night": {      "in": 0.00
        "mm": 0.0       }
        "snow_allday": {        "in": 0
        "cm": 0     }
        "snow_day": {       "in": 0
        "cm": 0     }
        "snow_night": {     "in": 0
        "cm": 0     }
        "maxwind": {        "mph": 10
        "kph": 16
        "dir": "WNW"
        "degrees": 302      }
        "avewind": {        "mph": 8
        "kph": 13
        "dir": "West"
        "degrees": 272      }
        "avehumidity": 46
        "maxhumidity": 51
        "minhumidity": 30       }       ]       }   }}
---------------------------
        mph: 8,
```

### Reply for Sydney, Australia

```
{   "response": {       "version": "0.1"        
"termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html"        
"features": {       "geolookup": 1      
        "conditions": 1     
        "forecast": 1       }   }       
    "location": {       "type":"INTLCITY"
        "country":"AU"
        "country_iso3166":"AU"
        "country_name":"Australia"
        "state":"NW"
        "city":"Sydney"
        "tz_short":"EST"
        "tz_long":"Australia/Sydney"
        "lat":"-33.95000076"
        "lon":"151.17999268"
        "zip":"00000"
        "magic":"1"
        "wmo":"94767"
        "l":"/q/zmw:00000.1.94767"
        "requesturl":"global/stations/94767.html"
        "wuiurl":"http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/94767.html"
        "nearby_weather_stations": {        "airport": {        "station": [        { "city":"Sydney Airport"
 "state":""
 "country":"Australia"
 "icao":"YSSY"
 "lat":"-33.95000076"
 "lon":"151.18333435" }
        { "city":"Sydney"
 "state":""
 "country":"AU"
 "icao":"YSSY"
 "lat":"-33.95000076"
 "lon":"151.17999268" }
        { "city":"Richmond (NSW)"
 "state":""
 "country":"AU"
 "icao":"YSRI"
 "lat":"-33.59999847"
 "lon":"150.77999878" }     ]       }       
        "pws": {        "station": [        {       "neighborhood":"Matraville"
        "city":"Sydney"
        "state":"NSW"
        "country":"AUSTRALIA"
        "id":"INSWMATR2"
        "lat":-33.957550
        "lon":151.230850
        "distance_km":4
        "distance_mi":2     }
        {       "neighborhood":"Bardwell Park"
        "city":"Sydney"
        "state":"New South Wales"
        "country":"AUSTRALIA"
        "id":"INEWSOUT37"
        "lat":-33.938381
        "lon":151.124359
        "distance_km":5
        "distance_mi":3     }
        {       "neighborhood":"APRSWXNET Sydney AU"
        "city":"Little Bay"
        "state":"NW"
        "country":"AU"
        "id":"MD5399"
        "lat":-33.958500
        "lon":151.240677
        "distance_km":5
        "distance_mi":3     }
        {       "neighborhood":""
        "city":"Pyrmont"
        "state":"NEW SOUTH WALES"
        "country":"AUSTRALIA"
        "id":"INEWSOUT155"
        "lat":-33.871807
        "lon":151.194977
        "distance_km":8
        "distance_mi":5     }
        {       "neighborhood":"Woolloomooloo"
        "city":"Woolloomooloo"
        "state":"NSW"
        "country":"AUSTRALIA"
        "id":"INSWWOOL3"
        "lat":-33.874527
        "lon":151.220734
        "distance_km":9
        "distance_mi":5     }
        {       "neighborhood":"Old\u0027s Park"
        "city":"Penshurst"
        "state":"NSW"
        "country":"AUSTRALIA"
        "id":"INSWPENS2"
        "lat":-33.958290
        "lon":-208.924866
        "distance_km":9
        "distance_mi":5     }
        {       "neighborhood":"Searl Road"
        "city":"Cronulla"
        "state":"NSW"
        "country":"AUSTRALIA"
        "id":"INSWCRON2"
        "lat":-34.052074
        "lon":151.148605
        "distance_km":11
        "distance_mi":7     }
        {       "neighborhood":"Cronulla - Cecil Apartments"
        "city":"Cronulla - Sydney"
        "state":"NSW"
        "country":"AUSTRALIA"
        "id":"INSWSYDN19"
        "lat":-34.054329
        "lon":151.153656
        "distance_km":11
        "distance_mi":7     }
        {       "neighborhood":"The Shire - Caringbah South"
        "city":"Sydney"
        "state":"New South Wales"
        "country":"Australia"
        "id":"INSWCARI2"
        "lat":-34.048203
        "lon":151.120697
        "distance_km":12
        "distance_mi":7     }
        {       "neighborhood":"Kareela"
        "city":"Kareela"
        "state":"NSW"
        "country":"AUSTRALIA"
        "id":"INSWKIRR2"
        "lat":-34.020538
        "lon":151.075287
        "distance_km":12
        "distance_mi":7     }
        {       "neighborhood":"Caringbah South"
        "city":"Caringbah South"
        "state":"NSW"
        "country":"AUSTRALIA"
        "id":"INSWCARI3"
        "lat":-34.054550
        "lon":151.115799
        "distance_km":13
        "distance_mi":7     }
        {       "neighborhood":"Sutherland Shire"
        "city":"Caringbah South"
        "state":"NEW SOUTH WALES"
        "country":"Australia"
        "id":"INEWSOUT125"
        "lat":-34.059315
        "lon":151.117416
        "distance_km":13
        "distance_mi":8     }
        {       "neighborhood":"Lower North Shore"
        "city":"Linley Point (Lane Cove)"
        "state":"NEW SOUTH WALES"
        "country":"AUSTRALIA"
        "id":"INEWSOUT83"
        "lat":-33.826977
        "lon":151.151077
        "distance_km":13
        "distance_mi":8     }
        {       "neighborhood":"Gymea Bay South of Sydney near Royal National Park"
        "city":"Sydney"
        "state":"NSW"
        "country":"Australia"
        "id":"ISYDNEY2"
        "lat":-34.047691
        "lon":151.079971
        "distance_km":14
        "distance_mi":8     }
        {       "neighborhood":"Willoughby"  
[some more text here]
    ---------------------------
            mph: 7,
```

---

### Problem

This is the reply from `Weather Underground` for two different cities. In case of Mumbai, it just gives data about one city however in case of Sydney, it gives the data about many locations around Sydney.

I want to be able to extract information from this `JSON` reply in a consistent manner. So far, I use `String` methods for some not-so-reliable extraction.
How do I go about doing that ?

### Code

```
package test;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils;

import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;


public class TestGson {

    URL callToApi;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGson();
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public TestGson(){
        try{
            sendCallToApi();
            readJson();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void sendCallToApi(){
        try{
            callToApi = new URL("http://api.wunderground.com/api" +
                    "/[API KEY HERE]" +
                    "/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/" +
                    "Australia/" +
                    "Sydney.json");
        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void readJson() throws IOException{
        Gson g = new Gson();
        String wdf = null;
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(callToApi.openStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);
        String message = "hello";
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

        while(true){
            message = reader.readLine();

            if(message == null){
                break;
            }else{
                if(message.contains("mph")){
                    wdf = message;
                }
                buf.append(message);
            }
        }
        message = buf.toString();
        System.out.println(message.replaceAll(",","\n"));
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        wdf = wdf.replace("\"", "");
        System.out.println(wdf);
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Comment: There is a [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332611/how-do-i-extract-value-from-json) but my case is different cause my JSON reply has multiple.... 'tags' with the name "city" in it.

Comment: 1) I would recommend using [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) for data retrieval. 2) I would recommend browsing through the [GSON user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide), particularly the section on [Object Mapping](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples).

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826237/reading-a-json-reply-from-weatherunderground) it is the same question...

Comment: @bmorris591 have a look at the one who asked the question - it is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a serialized object - this means it is very amenable to deserialization. This allows you to turn your JSON into a java object that you can query at will.
First you would need an appropriate java bean - the structure of your JSON is simple so that shouldn't be hard.
You can then use a tool such as [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) to read your data and put it onto the bean.

Comment: I was going over `GSON` for deserialization/serialization. The [example here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOCObject-Examples) shows how easy it is **BUT** my content is already in a `String` form. Is it possible to read the JSON directly from the input stream of the URL and then extract the values ?

Comment: How about [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi) or [this](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming)

Comment: Finished deserializing with GSON, thanks for the help anyways! :)